# Where is the last riddler destructible on Founders' Island?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I don't know if there's a game glitch or I'm missing something but I have completed every challenge and every riddle except the 15 "destructible a symbol of strength to overcome" on Founders Island and I cannot find it on the map or any help in walkthrough. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Founders' Island can be a bit tricky when it comes to trophy locations. If you have beat up all of the Riddler informants and still don't see them on your map, it may mean you need to go underground. Some of the trophies for the Founders' Island portion are underground in the subway section of the map. Be sure to check there for all of the rest of the items

Here's also a video of where everything is: